# How to correct Expected type error?

Tags: ios, swift

I have followed one article to write code. It gives me this Expected type error.

This is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    startUpdateLoop()
    animateControlPoints()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just check the error first. It gives you the information you need:

```
Expected type
```

If you get such an error, just check the documentation apple provides for this method and check if everything you've set, is correct.

[touchesBegan-documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:)

As you see, the documentation shows, that your implementation is different than the one, apple provides:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

As you can see, you need to set the type of your `Set` to `UITouch`. Currently this value is empty:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    startUpdateLoop()
    animateControlPoints()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `touchesBegan` method expects `touches` as a parameter which in the case of your code is just `Set<>`. It is expecting to see a `Set` of something like an `NSObject`. Here is an example of what it could except:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {...}
```

If you are using Swift 2 and Xcode 7 then you may notice a difference in this override as well.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {...}
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:) is a link to how this method works.